# Duplicate route named `index` error

Tags: javascript, ember.js, routes, url-routing, ember-cli

My application has links as `abc.com` which is a homepage and `abc.com/user123`(has a dynamic segment) which is a user-logged in specific profile page.

Earlier, I achieved this by doing:

```
this.route('index',{path:'/'}, function (){});
this.route('index', {path:'/:u_name'} , function() {});
```

Now, after upgrading to 2.10, I am **unable** to create the required links in my router.js using the above way. It gives rise to the following error in the console:

> ember.debug.js:55283 Uncaught Error: You may not add a duplicate route named `index.loading`.

Omitting any one of the two paths does not allow me to achieve the intended result.

Try visiting `/` and `/user123` on this [Ember Twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/9c27b156841de7e8541b7e3a652b21e8)

What's the *new* way to accomplish links like `abc.com` and `abc.com/user123`?

Comment: You will be interested in this [discussion](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/14585)

Comment: Aha! Thank you @kumkanillam

Answer (score 1):

Ankush.

I think I already said something about this in slack, but I just ran across it trying to deal with many error routes.

For the record, I think that the answer is to leave the 'index' out. It's trying to be helpful by having an implicit route, but it often just confuses things.

```
  this.route('flowers', function() {
    this.route('flower-list', { path: '/' });
    this.route('flower-detail', { path: '/:id'});
  });
```

or in a slightly more complex nesting

```
  this.route('flowers', function() {
    this.route('loading');
    this.route('flower-list', { path: '/' }, function() {
      this.route('quick-view', { path: '/:id'});
    });
    this.route('flower-detail', { path: '/:id'});
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

In this [emberjs bug report](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/14585) discussed not to have this kind of route configuration.
Despite of this, if you would like to have same feature, then try my attempt. let me know if this is working for you.

[Twiddle Link](https://ember-twiddle.com/6333f171d3dc40b09d43194212cabdf7?openFiles=router.js%2C)

I created `profile-index` route,

- Its route extends `index` route
- Its controller extends `index` controller
- Its template is `index.hbs`
  Typically you will use all the files specific to `index` route to `profile-index`

**router.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import config from './config/environment';

const Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: 'none',
  rootURL: config.rootURL
});

Router.map(function() {
  // BOTH '/' and '/user123' will work now
  this.route('index',{path: '/'}); 
  this.route('profile-index',{path: '/:u_name'});
});

export default Router;
```

**routes/index.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  eUserName: undefined,
  model(params){
    this.set('eUsername', params.u_name);
    return [1,2];
  },
  setupController(controller,model){
    this._super(...arguments);
    controller.set('eUsername',this.get('eUsername'));
  } 
});
```

**routes/profile-index.js** this will render `index.hb`s not `profile-index.hbs`

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import IndexRoute from './index';
export default IndexRoute.extend({
  templateName:'index',   
});
```

**controllers/index.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Controller.extend({   
  isProfilePageShown: Ember.computed('eUsername', function(){        
    return this.get('eUsername') ? true : false;
  }),       
  isHomePageShown: Ember.computed('isProfilePageShown', function(){
    return this.get('isProfilePageShown') ? false : true;
  })
});
```

**controllers/profile-index.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import IndexController from './index';
export default IndexController.extend({  
});
```

**templates/index.hbs**

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import IndexController from './index';
export default IndexController.extend({  
});
```